# sed print only pattern match

Tags: regex, sed, nmap

I am trying to get versions for services in a gnmap file.  A typical line looks like:

```
Host: 192.x.x.x ()    Ports: 21/open/tcp//ftp//HP JetDirect ftpd/, 23/open/tcp//telnet//HP JetDirect printer telnetd (No password)/, 80/open/tcp//http//HP-ChaiSOE 1.0 (HP LaserJet http config)/, 443/open/tcp//ssl|http//HP-ChaiSOE 1.0 (HP LaserJet http config)/, 515/open/tcp//printer///, 631/open/tcp//http//HP-ChaiSOE 1.0 (HP LaserJet http config)/, 7627/open/tcp//http//HP-ChaiSOE 1.0 (HP LaserJet http config)/, 9100/open/tcp/////, 14000/open/tcp//tcpwrapped///    Seq Index: 25   IP ID Seq: Incremental
```

I need to match specific "open" ports and print only the matching expression.  I have tried:

```
cat file | sed -n "/ 80\/open\/tcp\/\*\/\*\/\*\/\*\//p"
```

I need the result to be:

```
80/open/tcp//http//HP-ChaiSOE 1.0 (HP LaserJet http config)/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same using grep with the -o (--only-matching) option:

```
cat teste | grep -o "80\/open\/tcp\/[^,]*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way,

```
sed 's|.*, 80\([^,]*\).*|80\1|'
```

and, to avoid matching say '`8080`' here,

```
sed 's|.*, 80\/\([^,]*\).*|80/\1|'
```

But, I think, there is a better output form of NMAP that will make your life easier.
And, you will find more exact ways for this [grepable output](http://nmap.org/book/output-formats-grepable-output.html) in nmap documentation.

Comment: Actually a gnmap file is the grepable file.  Grep grabs the whole line.  I need only the output that I listed above.  Unfortunately the command you listed does not result in printing the result I am looking for.